# Advice: Interview in 3 hours

Tags: linux

I am about to interview for a summer position wherein I would be administering a linux system (in an intern sort of way). Experience is preferred, but I have zero experience as a sysadmin. I have had a job fixing undergrad computers, I am a math major, I am a proficient programmer, and I have been reading this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/filesystems.html

Questions: Which parts of that guide are most important? What strengths, considering my experience, should I play up? Any other generic advice?

Thanks for any help! I am hoping to get this position as more of a learning experience than as a job

Comment: If you don't have experience, you're going to have a hard time faking it. Be honest. "I have zero experience as a sysadmin, but I'm willing to learn." I'll hire someone like that any day over someone who tries to bullshit me.

Answer (score 3):

Oh god.  There's no way I can possibly divulge my years of interview experience into a simple answer.

Tips:

1. It's OK not to know the answer, as long as you've some idea how to find it.  Google is acceptable, in my eyes.  So is Serverfault.
2. Might be worth having a look at standard TCP ports. (I've been asked that in the past).
3. Take a look at the LPI exams and mention you plan to do the training and exams.

Good luck.

Comment: Agreed. Be honest. If you don't know an answer tell them that you don't know but you want to learn. Let them know that you're looking for an opportunity to "break in" to this profession and that what you lack in knowledge and experience you'll make up for with hard work, dedication and determination.